# Delete field contents from the structure?

Tags: abap

I want to clear that field from a structure.

First I am reading a row from the database into my structure `ls_mara`:

```
SELECT SINGLE mfrpn, ean11, matnr, prdha FROM mara INTO @DATA(ls_mara)
    WHERE matnr EQ @lv_matnr.
```

I have a table : ZADOBE_CODE and it involved matnr and prdha.

I need to check matnr and prdha and if I find same data in ZADOBE_CODE, then I must delete the field `ls_mara-mfrpn`. I wrote that:

```
SELECT SINGLE matnr, prdha FROM zadobe_code INTO @DATA(ls_zadobe_code)
    WHERE matnr EQ @ls_mara-matnr OR prdha EQ @ls_mara-prdha.

IF ls_zadobe_code IS NOT INITIAL.
"DELETE mfrpn FROM ls_mara.
ELSE.
ENDIF.
```

But my delete row is wrong. How can I write?

Comment: This question is unclear. The subject says you want to delete data from a structure, but the question body says you want to delete a row from a table.  But reading further, it appears that you don't actually want to delete the whole row but only clear a single field from that row. Or perhaps you want to clear that field from the structure `ls_mara` in memory and not permanently on the database? Please clarify what you actually mean.

Comment: @Philipp yes, I want to clear that field from the structure it's ls_mara-mfrpn.
This is my psoude code:
If zadobe_code-matnr = ls_mara-matnr OR zadobe_code-prdha = ls_mara-prdha
delete ls_mara-mfrpn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DELETE` statement is for deleting whole rows from a table (either database or internal, depending on how you write it). According to your comments, that's not what you want to do.

If you want to clear a field from a structure in memory, then you can do that either with `CLEAR ls_mara-mfrnp.` or by simply assigning an empty string to it with `ls_mara-mfrnp = ''`.